# Copy password from notepad file and use that to open and excel

Tags: vba, txt

Need quick help here

I am working on a project where my macro File (Lets call it JP.xlsm) has to open another file which contains user data (User_data file is password protected) and copy data from it to macro file.

But problem is USER_data file is password protected and its dynamic it changes every month and as per our policy we cannot store passwords in macros/scripts. So we are storing the password in a txt file in a folder.

I want that my macro should open the User_admin file and then txt file copies the password from txt file and puts into user admin file.

Please someone help me here

Previously i had written this below code

```vb
Sub OpenHardLockedUsers()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date

    MyPath = "C:\Users\xxxxx"

    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)

    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If

        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
'*************Giving password to open the file*************

    Workbooks.Open (MyPath & LatestFile), Password:="d1xl+6/ET3KB"
```

Comment: Where is your code failing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim pw
'...
'...
pw = GetContent("path\To\The\File\pw.txt")
Workbooks.Open (MyPath & LatestFile, Password:=pw)
'...
```

For reading the file with the password:

```vb
'read and return all content from a files
Function GetContent(f As String) As String
    GetContent = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  opentextfile(f, 1).readall()
End Function
```